# Regarding php Regular expression filenames

Tags: php, regex

**Edit: (here is a better live example:**

http://vzio.com/upload/reg_pattern.php)

I am very bad at regular expressions, but I have a regular expression that is working okay, except for one issue:

```
/\/(.*?).php/
```

I only need this regular expression to find things like:

**/this-a-valid-page.php** {some words here}  **/anotherpage.php**  { some words here} http://www.google.com

but do not find URLs  the problem i am having is that it find this parts of full URLS i want it to avoid these all together. http:/**/www.google.com/page.php**  because i have another function that does something different than the filename reg exp.

Comment: Can you give 2 or 3 exact input->output examples? I don't understand from the one given.

Comment: Here is an online example http://vzio.com/upload/reg_pattern.php

Answer (score 1):

`/^\/(.*?)\.php$/`

```
bash:~$ php -a
php > $test = array('pass' => '/test.php', 'fail' => 'http://example.com/test.php');
php > echo preg_match('/^\/(.*?)\.php$/', $test['pass']);
True
php > echo preg_match('/^\/(.*?)\.php$/', $test['fail']);
False
```

Comment: thanks for the post, but for some reason it works for one but not more than one ie-> /home-splash-add.php this is a test to see if it will do them all /home-splash-add.php 

it misses both of them

Comment: It should work, only thing required is the / needs to be the first character, and the end should be .php, hence the carrot and dollar signs.